# Insert Overwrite in data bricks overwriting complete data in table?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am have two table 1 is with 50K records and other is with 2.5K records and I want to update this 2.5K records into table one. Currently I was doing this by using INSERT OVERWRITE statement in spark Mapr cluster. And I want to do same in azure databricks. Where I created 2 tables in databricks and read data from on-prem servers into azure then using INSERT OVERWRITE statement. But I was doing this my previus/History data was completely replaced with new data.

**In Mapr cluster**

```
src_df_name.write.mode("overwrite").format("hive").saveAsTable(s"cs_hen_mbr_stg") //stage table with 2.5K records.

spark.sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE cs_hen_mbr_hist " +
          s"SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('INID',stg.INID,'SEG_NBR',stg.SEG_NBR,'SRC_ID',stg.SRC_ID, "+
          s"'SYS_RULE',stg.SYS_RULE,'MSG_ID',stg.MSG_ID, " +
          s"'TRE_KEY',stg.TRE_KEY,'PRO_KEY',stg.PRO_KEY, " +
          s"'INS_DATE',stg.INS_DATE,'UPDATE_DATE',stg.UPDATE_DATE,'STATUS_KEY',stg.STATUS_KEY) AS key, "+
          s"stg.MEM_KEY,stg.INDV_ID,stg.MBR_ID,stg.SEGO_ID,stg.EMAIL, " +
          s"from cs_hen_mbr_stg stg" )
```

By doing above in mapr cluster I was able to update values.But i was trying same in azure databricks My history data is getting lost.

**In Databriks**

```
val VW_HISTORY_MAIN=spark.read.format("parquet").option("header","true").load(s"${SourcePath}/VW_HISTORY")
VW_HISTORY_MAIN.write.mode("overwrite").format("hive").saveAsTable(s"demo.cs_hen_mbr_stg") //writing this to table in databricks.

spark.sql(s"INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE cs_hen_mbr_hist " +
          s"SELECT NAMED_STRUCT('INID',stg.INID,'SEG_NBR',stg.SEG_NBR,'SRC_ID',stg.SRC_ID, "+
          s"'SYS_RULE',stg.SYS_RULE,'MSG_ID',stg.MSG_ID, " +
          s"'TRE_KEY',stg.TRE_KEY,'PRO_KEY',stg.PRO_KEY, " +
          s"'INS_DATE',stg.INS_DATE,'UPDATE_DATE',stg.UPDATE_DATE,'STATUS_KEY',stg.STATUS_KEY) AS key, "+
          s"stg.MEM_KEY,stg.INDV_ID,stg.MBR_ID,stg.SEGO_ID,stg.EMAIL, " +
          s"from cs_hen_mbr_stg stg" )
```

Why it is not working with databricks?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error it is completely replacing with old data.

Comment: The nature of OVERWRITE is to replace the data, I'm surprised that it appends the data for you in the MapR cluster.

Azure Databricks, you can use INSERT INTO which appends the data, and if your destination is DELTA then it also gives you UPDATE, DELETE, and TimeTravel capability.

Comment: Thanks you. I got the reason behind this. It is because it is an HBase table in mapr cluster.